# What is the best method of defining a score function for SKLearn Custom Estimator of a baseline fitting algorithm

Tags: scikit-learn, time-series

I am attempting to optimize a baseline fitting algorithm for signal preprocessing by instantiating it as a SKLearn Custom Estimator and using GridSearchCV. How can I define a custom score to optimize the baseline fit, i.e. maximise fit function smoothness and intersections with the signal function? Also, is that a rational way of defining an optimal fit?

The end goal is a SKLearn Pipeline with several preprocessing steps prior to deconvolution through model fit optimization.